Can I ignore the negative time value in this space-time coordinate transformation with $v = 0$?
When transforming a space-time event $P = (ct, x, y, z)$ from the inertial frame $I$ to the inertial frame $I'$ and $I'$ has the relative speed $v = 0$ observed from $I$, I want to check whether $t = t'$ is true. I get the following equation using the Minkowskian metric:
$$(ct)^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = (ct')^2 - x'^2 - y'^2 - z'^2.$$
Simplifying this equation by using $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x'^2 + y'^2 + z'^2$ as the euclidian distance from the 3D-space point $(x, y, z)$ stays the same after the coordinate transformation yields to this equation:
$$(ct)^2 = (ct')^2.$$
So in theory, we get the two solutions $t' = \pm t$. Now I suppose that only $t' = t$ is a solution since we would only get this solution when calculating $t'$ by using the matrix form which is mentioned in this Phys.SE post. Still, I'm not 100% sure about that so can I really ignore the solution $t' = -t$?

Time reversal is a valid Lorentz transformation, so in that sense $t'=-t$ is a valid solution.  The full Lorentz group, including time reversal and space inversion, is relevant for say looking at the symmetries of a Lagrangian.  However, when we are talking about what one can expect to see in different reference frames, we restrict to using only proper orthochronous Lorentz transformations, which by definition exclude time reversal and space inversion, so in that case $t' = -t$ would be ruled out as a valid solution.

It is not completely clear to me from which assumption you start.
Maybe the follow will be helpful (I assume you are used to Einstein sum convention). Let's focus on linear coordinate transformations, i.e., $x'^{\mu} = \Lambda^\mu{}_{\nu} x^\nu$. We want that laws of nature look the same in system $x^\mu$ as in $x'^\mu$. In particular, we want the Minkowski metric to be the same, i.e., $\tilde \eta_{\mu\nu} := \Lambda^{-1}{}^{\alpha}{}_{\mu} \Lambda^{-1}{}^{\beta}{}_{\nu} \eta_{\alpha \beta} \stackrel{!}{=} \eta_{\mu \nu}$.
This condition restricts the allowed matrices to $\operatorname{O}(1,3) \subset \operatorname{GL}(1,3)$ (This is the analogue to the orthogonal group in the Euclidean case). However, there are still transformation we want to restrict. Note, that coordinate change
$t' = t, x' = -x, y' = y, z' = z$
Is generated by a matrix $\Lambda \in \operatorname{O}(1,3)$. But this transformation changes the parity of space (it mirrors the hole universe at the $yz$ plane. In order to exclude this, we impose the additional constraint for the allowed coordinate transformations that $\det \Lambda = 1$. This restricts the allowed transformations to $\operatorname{SO}(1,3)$. But still there is the following coordinate transformation:
$t' = -t , x' =-x, y' = y, z'= z$
Which mirrors the spacial world and the time direction simultaneously. Therefore, usually on imposes the condition $t_1' > t_2' \Leftrightarrow t_1 > t_2$, i.e., the chronological order is preserved. This restricts the allows transformations to orthochronous Lorentz group $\Lambda \in \operatorname{SO}^+(1,3)$.
When talking about physical Lorentz transformations, one typically refers to $\Lambda \in \operatorname{SO}^+(1,3)$.
Note, the coordinate changes by orthochronous Lorentz transformations are the only coordinate transformations you can arrive at by smoothly changing the original coordinate system. As you cannot flip a coin by continuously turning it clockwise (such that it is always head up), you cannot change your direction of time by accelerating to a different Lorentz frame.
